# Unable to Connect to Docker Registery from Cent OS 7 VM

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-registry

I'm trying to connect to Docker Registery by running command "sudo docker run hello-world" after installing Docker Version 24.05 build ced0996 and getting following Error:

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally

docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 34.205.13.154:443: connect: connection refused.

See 'docker run --help'.

The Cent OS Installed Version is : 7.9.2009. I've created daemon.json and added dns entries for 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and restarted docker service still unable to connect. I've run ping command to check and see whether connectity from VM to outside is working or not, I can see packets being trasmitted and received ok with 0% loss.

I've also run sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones and it retunred interface for dockero along with etho.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.